# Different display for pringing same variable in python 2.7.11 class method

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning python just now, and confusing a lot question of python.

Below is one question:

class people:

```
 def __init__(self,name):
      self.name = name
      print self.name
```

> p = people('test')

test

> p.name

'test'

why different output for people('test') and p.name? string test with/without single quote?

Answer (score 1):

When you explicitly `print` something, you get the `str()` of that object.  When you type an expression in the Python interpreter, you get the `repr()` of that object.  Generally speaking, `repr` is more detailed, and gives some indication of the type of the object; often it is identical to a Python expression that would create that object.  In particular, `repr` of a string is always enclosed in quotes, so that you can tell that it is a string.

Comment: As I understand, str() seems show the quotes: >>> p = "test"
>>> p
'test'
>>> print p
test
>>> str(p)
'test'      >>> repr(p)
"'test'"

Comment: ``str()`` of a string does nothing to it.  However, ``str(p)`` as an interactive expression is effectively the same thing as ``repr(str(p))``.